# How to convert a bitmap to a RoundRect bitmap?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawable, paint

#### I'm trying to convert Bitmap to RoundRect shape. And i'm confused to use

```
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.saveLayer();
```

It's ok if I drawRoundRect first.

```
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {
  Drawable drawable =  new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), bitmap);
  Bitmap destBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), 
  bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(destBitmap);
  Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  RectF srcRect = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
  canvas.drawRoundRect(srcRect, mRadiusX, mRadiusY,  paint);
  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
  canvas.saveLayer(srcRect, paint, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
  drawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
  drawable.draw(canvas);
  canvas.restore();
  return destBitmap;
}
```

But, it dosen't work if I draw bitmap first. Why?

```
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {
  Drawable drawable =  new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), bitmap);
  Bitmap destBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), 
  bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(destBitmap);
  Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  RectF srcRect = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
  drawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
  drawable.draw(canvas);
  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
  canvas.saveLayer(srcRect, paint, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
  canvas.drawRoundRect(srcRect, mRadiusX, mRadiusY,  paint);
  canvas.restore();
  return destBitmap;
}
```

Also, I don't want to create a new Bitmap, can I drawRoundRect on the bitmap directly to convert roundRect shape? like this:

```
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
  Path path = new Path();
  path.addRoundRect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),50, 50, 
  Path.Direction.CW);
  canvas.clipPath(path);
  return bitmap;
}
```

Doesn't work.

I have some questions:

1. Do I have to "saveLayer" and "restore" if I use "PorterDuffXfermode"?
2. Do I have to create a new Bitmap, and draw on it ? can I draw the src Bitmap which is mutable?

Comment: simply use `BitmapShader` - you dont need any `saveLayer` / `restore` and `PorterDuffXfermode`

Comment: and if you are not sure how to use `BitmapShader` see `RoundedBitmapDrawable` source file

Comment: @pskink thank you a lot,I'll see RoundedBitmapDrawable  source code. but i really want konw why it doesn't work.  I use drawRoundRect ,select Mode.SRC_IN, then draw the bitmap, it is ok to get a roundrect bitmap, but i change the order, draw the bitmap first, select  Mode.DST_IN, then drawRoundRect, it failed. I think they are supposed to be the same.